# Is there a way to further optimize Graham Scan algorithm to find the convex hull?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, convex-hull, grahams-scan

I went through chan's algorithm. It doesn't seem much better to me.
Is there a way I can replace that sorting part in graham scan with anything else ? so that O(nlogn) time could be further reduced.
Java implementation is preferred.

Comment: This is a bit too broad in my opinion.

Comment: I don't know what grahamscan is but the usual lower bound for sorting things is nlogn (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list)

Comment: Chan's algorithm is O(n log v) where v is the number of vertexes in the *output*. That is, v < n. It definitely has a better worst-case complexity.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to optimise the sorting step is to avoid considering points which will not be part of the convex hull. This is called Akl-Toussaint heuristic http://www-cgrl.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/publications/fast.convex.hull.algorithm.pdf. You can quickly scan through all vertices and find a quadrilateral formed the pointset (you can get the four points as the extrema of for all vertices in ±(x+y), ±(x-y)), then just delete all the vertices inside this quadrilateral.

After this you can use Graham's scan or Andrew's monotone chain algorithm —my favourite, both are of O(n log n)complexity. *Note that, like @Chill mentioned in comments above, Chan's method is optimal*.

In practice this method is much faster than applying one of the algorithms to the point set without any filtering.

The paper I linked above mentions a "throw-away" idea in the conclusions section. This is a slight improvement, since we can throw away most of the vertices *while* searching for the quadrilateral itself. I am attaching a snippet just for this heuristic.

```
/**
 * Given verts: Array(Points).
 */

/*
 * if we have more than 100 points use Akl-Toussaint heuristic to remove
 *  points that we know are surely not part of the hull.
 * S.G. Akl & Godfried Toussaint, 1977,  "A Fast Convex-hull Algorithm"
 */
if (verts.length > 100) {
    var min = Math.min,
        max = Math.max;
    var minU = minL = maxU = maxL = verts[0];
    var minUval = minU.x - minU.y;
    var minLval = minL.x + minL.y;
    var maxUval = maxU.x + maxU.y;
    var maxLval = maxL.x - maxL.y;
    var xMin = yMin = xMax = yMax = 0;
    var vertList = [];
    for (i = 0 ; i < verts.length; ++i) {
        var v = verts[i];
        var x = v.x;
        var y = v.y;
        if (!(x > xMin && x < xMax && y > yMin && y < yMax)) {
            vertList.push(v);
            var sum = x + y;
            var diff = x - y;
            if (diff < minUval) minU = v;
            if (diff > maxLval) maxL = v;
            if (sum < minLval) minL = v;
            if (sum > maxUval) maxU = v;
            minUval = minU.x - minU.y;
            maxLval = maxL.x - maxL.y;
            minLval = minL.x + minL.y;
            maxUval = maxU.x + maxU.y;
            xMin = max(minU.x, minL.x);
            yMin = max(minL.y, maxL.y);
            xMax = min(maxU.x, maxL.x);
            yMax = min(minU.y, maxU.y);
        }
    }

    // reset the vert's array, and do one more filtering pass 
    // on vertList
    verts.length = 0;
    for (i = 0 ; i < vertList.length; ++i) {
        var v = vertList[i];
        var x = v.x;
        var y = v.y;
        if (!(x > xMin && x < xMax && y > yMin && y < yMax))
            verts.push(v);
    }
    // verts now only contains a subset of vertices.
}
// Run a convexhull algorithm on verts.
// ...
```